# Probability of full house when a player already has 2 cards of the same value (ex 5 of hearts/clubs) when drawing next 3 cards (total 5)

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, conditional-probability, poker

I am having trouble trying to calculate the probability of getting a full house when a player already has 2 cards in their hand. For example, if they have a 5 of hearts and 5 of clubs, then they can either draw another 5 and draw a pair, or draw a three of a kind. I am unsure how to solve this and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your two cases are the way to go.  Just work them separately.  How many ways can you draw three of a kind from the remaining deck, for instance.

Comment: Would you then just combine them using multiplication or addition?

Comment: Addition. They are disjoint events. It is not possible that you draw another five plus a pair at the same time as drawing three of a kind. You are only drawing 3 more cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case 1: Draw a separate three-of-a-kind. There are 12 ranks that you do not have. Choose 1 and choose 3 of the four suits. Divide by the number of ways to draw three more cards.

Case 2: Draw one of the remaining cards of the same rank you already have, choose one of the remaining twelve ranks, and choose two of the four suits. Divide by the number of ways to draw three more cards.

Total probability:
$$\dfrac{\dbinom{12}{1}\dbinom{4}{3}+\dbinom{2}{1}\dbinom{12}{1}\dbinom{4}{2}}{\dbinom{50}{3}} = \dfrac{12}{1225}$$

Comment: So with disjoint events, can I think of them as events that have independent outcomes such that they cant effect each other?

Comment: Independent is not the same as disjoint. Outcomes that are mutually exclusive (if one occurs, then the other cannot) are disjoint. Outcomes that are independent are not necessarily disjoint. Example: drawing an Ace is independent from drawing a Heart, but it is possible you can draw a single card that is both an Ace and a Heart. These are independent events, but not disjoint. That means the probability of drawing an Ace of Hearts is equal to the product of the probabilities of drawing an ace and that of drawing a heart: $$P(\text{A of H}) = P(A)P(H) = \dfrac{1}{13}\cdot \dfrac{1}{4}$$

Comment: Ah, understood. Thank you for the clarification

Comment: Dependent events are ones where the probability of one affects the probability of the other. Example, drawing a face card vs drawing a King. $$P(\text{Face card}) = \dfrac{3}{13}, P(\text{King}) = \dfrac{1}{13}, P(\text{King, which is a face card}) = \dfrac{1}{13}\neq \dfrac{1}{13}\cdot \dfrac{3}{13}$$ These are not independent because once you draw a king, you always have a face card. Once you have a face card, one third of the time you have a king.

Comment: Say for example that the player has a King and a Queen and draws 3 cards, the probability of forming a full house is based around the disjoint events of either drawing 2 Kings and a queen or vice versa, being divided by the sample space?

Comment: Correct. Or, you can think of it like choose either kings or queens to be the 3-of-a-kind. The other will be a pair. $$\dfrac{\dbinom{3}{2}\dbinom{3}{1}+\dbinom{3}{1}\dbinom{3}{2}}{\dbinom{50}{3}} = \dfrac{\dbinom{2}{1}\dbinom{3}{2}\dbinom{3}{1}}{\dbinom{50}{3}}$$ You can get the same result counting different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative counting... Assume we have the two cards $5\heartsuit$ and $5\clubsuit$ in our hand.
(The probability in the general case is the same, here it helps to fix ideas.)

Then there remain $52-2=50$ cards, and we have no information about other cards.
We extract three cards, their order being important.

So there are totally $50\cdot 49\cdot 48$ cases. Each such case comes with the same probability, $1/(50\cdot 49\cdot 48)$. How many of these cases are favorable (for the full house)?

- The constellation $\{5?,X?,X?\}$ (as a set), $X\ne 5$, comes in the cases $5XX$, $X5X$, $XX5$. Here, the $?$ stays for a color as a joker, different colors are possible. There are two cases for the $5$, $52-4=48$ cases for the first $X$, and $3$ cases for the second $X$. We get $3\cdot2\cdot48\cdot3$ favorable cases with a full house $555XX$ (as a set).
- The constellation $\{X?,X?,X?\}$ (as a set), $X\ne 5$, comes (with same conventions) in with $52-4=48$ cases for the first $X$, $3$ cases for the second $X$, and $2$ cases for the third $X$, getting thus $48\cdot3\cdot2$ favorable.

The searched probability is thus
$$
\frac{48(3\cdot2\cdot3+3\cdot2)}{48\cdot 49\cdot 50}
=\frac{24}{49\cdot 50}
=\frac{12}{1225}\approx                                                                                                                                            
0.0097959183673469\dots
\ .
$$